# dpkg-reconfigure: not found when running in cron

Tags: debian, cron

I have a virtual server (debian) and the clock fails to sync from time to time (probably because i save/restore state with vboxheadlesstray).

To fix this issue I run `dpkg-reconfigure ntp && ntpq -p`, it works when I run it as root, but  doesn't work with cron. I have added it in `crontab -e` (as root user) and is using this line:

```
1 * * * * dpkg-reconfigure ntp && ntpq -p > /dev/null 2>&1
```

My ordinary user user get mail about it saying `/bin/sh: 1: dpkg-reconfigure: not found`, why is my ordinary user getting the mail and not root and what do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian, `dpkg-reconfigure` is located under `/usr/sbin`, and root obviously has it in his $PATH, ***but*** cron limits `$PATH` to `/usr/bin:/bin`, even for root.
See man 5 crontab :

```
Several  environment  variables  are  set  up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.
SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner.
PATH is set to "/usr/bin:/bin". HOME, SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab;
LOGNAME is the user that the job is running from, and may not be changed.
```

So you would have to modify your crontab :

- giving full path :
  `1 * * * * /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure ntp && ntpq -p > /dev/null 2>&1`
- or with modified $PATH :
  `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin

  1 * * * * dpkg-reconfigure ntp && ntpq -p > /dev/null 2>&1`

It would work, ***but*** it would not be clean :p
You'd better follow above recommandation, assuming you have a working ntp daemon, or just put that job instead :
`10 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate &>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg-reconfigure` is located in `/usr/sbin/` on my system:

```
martin@martin ~ % which dpkg-reconfigure
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure
```

Check the `PATH` variable in your crontab, maybe it's missing the `/usr/sbin/` directory?

Also, using `dpkg-reconfigure` just to force NTP to re-set the time doesn't seem like a particularly good idea, and `ntpq -p > /dev/null 2>&1` doesn't seem to do anything useful. According to the manpage, `-p` just lists the peers, so running that and piping the output to `/dev/null` should do essentially nothing.

Why don't you just run `/etc/init.d/ntp restart > /dev/null` from your crontab?

Answer (score 3):

Better yet add the following to ntp.conf

```
tinker panic 0
```

That way you dont have to restart ntp (which is not good).

Comment: Didn't work. Server clock still unsynced with this.

Comment: What does `ntpq -p` say?